# Data not appearing in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What i am trying to do is parse an XML and have the elements populate the table view. The XML parses fine and prints in console, but is unable to display in the table view. Here is my code for populating a cell:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        NSMutableDictionary *news = (NSMutableDictionary *)[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.textLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"title"]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"link"]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the storyboard? Have you checked to make sure the `Cell Identifier` is "cell" in storyboard, too?

Comment: @TroyBarrios post logs of your feed array.

Comment: I have tried printing the logs after inserting the object into the dictionary but nothing is printed.

Comment: @Troy Are you calling `[tableView reloadData]` after updating the feeds array.

Comment: No just when i finish parsing the XML.

Answer (score 3):

I  got it to display. Seems I forgot to set the data source in the viewDidLoad method... thank you everyone for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are only adding data to the text labels when you create a new one. Add the data to the view after the if statement.

UITableView will reuse cells when possible. When it does you will get an existing cell from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *news = (NSMutableDictionary*) [feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [news objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [news objectForKey:@"link"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't news have to declared outside of the if statement to be in scope?

Comment: I tried that solution, but the data is still not appearing in the table view.

Comment: try to reload the table when parshing completes

Comment: or put NSLog(@"%@",news);just below  NSMutableDictionary *news = (NSMutableDictionary*).... to check that you are getting data or not

Comment: It seems nothing is being added to the feeds array because when i try printing a log nothing appears.

Answer (score 1):

Fill the data After creating creating or reusing your cell . It will work fine now ,Use below code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

    NSMutableDictionary *news = (NSMutableDictionary *)[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[news objectForKey:@"link"]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    return cell;
}
```